# site search information to Universal Analytics from Google Tag Manager

Tags: search, google-analytics, seo, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

New to Google Tag Manager. Before we upgraded to Universal code, we have site search activated and working. We used the _ga.push to send search parameters to Google Analytic.

This works perfectly fine and our search query will look like this: `http://http://stackoverflow.com/searchresult?q=[Keyword]=mainsearch.`

Now that we have moved to Tag Manager, The site search is not showing in Google Analytic. I have no idea if this should automatically be picked up after we make the setting in Google Analytic or we will have to create a rule or tag to track the search query (?q).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will be picked up automatically as long as site search is configured in the view, there is a query parameter in the url, you do not accidentally remove the parameter in your view settings and you do not overwrite the location field in the GTM Analytics tag with something that does not contain the search parameter. If you have Chrome use the GA debugger extension to see if the location field is sent with the correct search parameter, if it is then your problem is with your view configuration.

Comment: @Eike, thanks for the reply. It is not picked up automatically in Google Analytic. The Site search is configured correctly in view setting in Google Analytic. We did not include site search parameter in the location field in GTM. The Location field in the GTM Analytics only have {{url path with fragment}} as we have a virtual page path. Nothing else is included in the Location field in GTM. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, your location field in GTM only contains only page path and the fragment identifier. GA picks the parameter with the search query from the location field. If you do not include it there then GA will not be able to track the search. So you'd need to add the query parameter for site search to your location field.